# About File System and Formatting Device

Tags: partitioning

I formatted a pen drive by using terminal and now I can use full 16GB(capacity) of pen drive, but before formatting it the capacity was 14.9GB.I just want to ask you ,how this can be possible to access full capacity of pen drive?Is there something that i have done wrong? I include a screenshot of terminal window showing the commands I entered.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please dont post screenshots of commands and use a copy/paste of commands.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't done anything wrong, except to misread 14.9 G**i**B as 14.9 GB.

They are two different units of measurement, like the computing equivalent of imperial and metric.  The clue is on the last line of output from `dd`:

```
16022241280 bytes (16 GB, 15 GiB) copied
```

Hard drives are sold in metric units (GB) where the prefixes (K, M, G) increase in multiples of 1000, but computers have traditionally used the larger binary units (GiB), where the prefixes increase in multiples of 2^10 (10 twos multiplied  together), equal to 1024.

Therefore a Gigabyte (GB) is 1000*1000*1000 bytes, while a Gibibyte (GiB) is 1024*1024*1024 bytes, and indeed `16.0*1000*1000*1000` is roughly equal to `14.9*1024*1024*1024`.

Comment: Thanks......for such a valuable information.I got my answer.